# How to print PDF/Image file direct from file picker using UIPrintInteractionController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to print a selected file(PDF) using 'UIDocumentPickerViewController' and 'UIPrintInteractionController' though printing screen appearing but nothing showing in page. Single blank page showing.

Here is code for Document picker

```
struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var filePath: URL?
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> DocumentPicker.Coordinator {
        return DocumentPicker.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .open)
        picker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DocumentPicker.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        
        var parent: DocumentPicker
        
        init(parent1: DocumentPicker){
            parent = parent1
        }
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            Print(fPath: urls.first!)
        }
```

Printing function

```
func Print(fPath: URL){

      
            let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
            printInfo.jobName = fPath.lastPathComponent
            printInfo.outputType = .general

            let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
            printController.printInfo = printInfo
            printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false

            printController.printingItem = fPath
            print(fPath.absoluteString)

            printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
           
            
        }
    }
```